# capistrano not running migrations in staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am using capistrano 3 and I run `cap staging deploy`. After various commands, it then runs `rake db:migrate`, which looks like this:

> INFO [f67aeefb] Running /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.1.2@core do
>   bundle exec rake db:migrate as deploy@10.10.4.131 DEBUG [f67aeefb]
>   Command: cd /var/www/mysite_staging/releases/20150617233945 && (
>   RAILS_ENV=staging /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.1.2@core do bundle
>   exec rake db:migrate ) DEBUG [f67aeefb]   "Env => staging"

The problem is the migration appears to have run in production, not in staging.

How can I ensure capistrano runs the migrations in staging when I specify staging during the deploy?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which of it did it, but by adding the following to staging.rb:

```
set :rails_env, 'staging'
set :database_name, 'core_staging'
```

And then in my apache virtual host adding:

```
RailsEnv staging
```

It seems to now recognize the staging database.